At what point do you start writing grants?
Throughout my PhD all my mentors wrote grants about projects or collections of projects that were at least 50% done, at a point where they may have already submitted a paper on parts of the grant to a journal/conference.
I am starting out as a new assistant professor without preliminary/feasibility data under my belt, and I am struggling with this cold start problem of having the time and energy to write grants, but without preliminary data to write convincingly and deeply as PIs who have basically already done half of the proposed technical work.
Does anyone have solutions or ideas about when is a good time to begin writing grants? Or how I can write a good grant without preliminary data.

In many cases, you won't even see an offer unless you can explain what Aim 1 is, where you intend to send it, and when.

This is from my perspective of mentoring early career faculty, and my own experience.
Unsurprisingly, my University put a tremendous amount of pressure on us to write and submit grants as soon as we got there (with nearly 60% overhead, why wouldn't they). My labs weren't even cleared for use yet, and I was sitting in workshops on how to submit an NSF Career grant. I see them continuing to do the same with incoming faculty. I don't think this is particularly fruitful as soon as you start. The only caveat is for grants that are only eligible for your first few years of tenure track (which often don't require any preliminary work).
Presumably you have negotiated some start-up support (which of course varies by field and university). This typically sees you through your first three years. I encourage starting faculty to just get organized in their first year and start generating some preliminary data. If you can publish anything in that timeframe, even better, it shows that you have been very productive (unfortunately failed grant applications show nothing to the outside world). Use this time to recruit students, build your website, get your feet wet with teaching, make connections internally, and attend a conference or two to maintain an external network (those are the people on grant panels after all).
Then in year 2 start testing the waters with grants - don't expect anything, but you never know, you may get lucky. What is most valuable at this point is that program managers start seeing your name, and hopefully you at the very least get some solid feedback to build on. If your grants get declined but you get some good feedback, keep improving and resubmit next cycle, don't give up. For NSF as an example, it often takes a round or two to finally get an idea funded. With that in mind, it is worthwhile to always have a few proposals rolling, don't rely on just one getting funded.
Good luck!

Good advice. I am submitting smaller ~100k grants anyway to "grease the wheels" mentally speaking. Maybe one will get in. And it helps with idea conceptualization anyhow.

First, get advice from your colleagues about what works in grants they have written. Ask them to review anything you propose.
Second, it is better to get started than to wait as an assistant prof. Grant seeking activity will probably be viewed positively by your colleagues.
Third, an old time grant strategy, perhaps still used, is to ask for a grant when the work is nearly done so that it is guaranteed for success. If you are granted funds, then submit those papers and use the funds to enable the next project. Then repeat... While this seems like deception it was widely used in the past. Ask your colleagues about this too.

Yes, the strategy in your third paragraph is how I have seen it done by everyone I know. But obviously there is a bit of a cold-start problem as an assistant professor. Basically I want to start writing grants immediately, even as my first projects are too nascent to bear fruit yet.

@user2562609 You're not starting research from scratch. What happened to your work from your PhD and Postdoc?

@user2562609 in some fields (mine included) that is looked down upon. Your independent career begins at tenure track, all previous work is that of your advisors.

@user71659 That research will be used by my former PIs for their own grants! That is not research I can really use as the main part of the grant where I serve as the primary or sole PI (can be used as supporting evidence of competency only).
